# How Can I convert a nested array of object into a flat Array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, flat

I've got this

```
 const nested =  [
    [{ id: 1, name: "carl" }],    
    [{ id: 2, name: "lety" }],
    [{ id: 3, name: "jim" }]
 ];
```

but I need this:

```
 const flat =  [
    { id: 1, name: "carl" },    
    { id: 2, name: "lety" },
    { id: 3, name: "jim" }
 ];
```

thanks so muchs

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to have only 1 value in your subarrays, you can try :

```
const flat = []

for (n of nested) {
    flat.push(n[0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nested.flat();` solved my issue